# Boost serialization unable to restore saved objects

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

This is how my class looks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include <fstream>

// include headers that implement a archive in simple text format
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class outer{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    public:
        int a;
        class inner{
            friend class boost::serialization::access;
            public:
                int a;
                inner(int a){
                    this->a = a;
                }
                template<class Archive>
                void serialize(Archive & ar,const unsigned int version){
                    ar & a;
                }
                inner(){
                }
        };
        vector<inner> inners;
        outer(int a){
            this->a = a;    
            inners.push_back(inner(this->a+1));     
        }
        outer(){
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar,const unsigned int version){
            ar & a;
            ar & inners;
        }
};

vector<outer> outers;
vector<outer> _outers;

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(outer);

int main(int, char*[]) {
    int i;
    std::ofstream ofs("filename.dat");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        outers.push_back(outer(i)); 

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << outers;
    std::ifstream ifs("filename.dat");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        // read class state from archive
        ia >> _outers;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I create a vector of `outer` class instances and write it out to a text stream (which seems to work fine). But when I read it back, I get the error:
*terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  input stream error*

The above is the entire self-contained code, compiled with:

```
g++ -I /path/to/boost test.cpp -lboost_serialization
```

How do I fix this, any ideas?

Comment: I assume that `outers` is declared somewhere else in the real main()?

Comment: Yes, `outers` is a vector of `outer` class instances.

Comment: Can you move that into the posted code?  (all variables you use, etc)  MCVE are appreciated.  And fix indentation, etc.

Comment: @Yakk Made the edits.

Comment: Did you include the vector serialization header?

Comment: Yes, that's included.

Comment: Please finish the MCVE -- it should be complete.  Include a minimal set of headers you need to include.  Confirm that when you compile and run your MCVE you get exactly the problem you are asking about.

Comment: @Yakk Edited. That's the entire code in one cpp file, self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing:

```
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
```

You need to close the output archive/stream before reading the file back:

```
int main() {
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("filename.dat");

        std::vector<outer> outers(5);
        std::iota(outers.begin(), outers.end(), 0u);

        {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
            oa << outers;
        }
    }

    {
        // read class state from archive
        std::vector<outer> _outers;
        std::ifstream ifs("filename.dat");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> _outers;

        for(auto& outer : _outers) {
            std::cout << "outer " << outer.a << "\n";

            for (auto& inner: outer.inners)
                std::cout << "   inner " << inner.a << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9425c119ac7e9993)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class outer {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

  public:
    int a;
    class inner {
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

      public:
        int a;
        inner(int a) { this->a = a; }
        template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) { ar &a; }
        inner() {}
    };
    std::vector<inner> inners;
    outer(int a = 0) : a(a), inners {a+1} { }

    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar &a;
        ar &inners;
    }
};


BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(outer)

int main(int, char *[]) {
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("filename.dat");

        std::vector<outer> outers(5);
        std::iota(outers.begin(), outers.end(), 0u);

        {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
            oa << outers;
        }
    }

    {
        // read class state from archive
        std::vector<outer> _outers;
        std::ifstream ifs("filename.dat");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> _outers;

        for(auto& outer : _outers) {
            std::cout << "outer " << outer.a << "\n";

            for (auto& inner: outer.inners)
                std::cout << "   inner " << inner.a << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
outer 0
   inner 1
outer 1
   inner 2
outer 2
   inner 3
outer 3
   inner 4
outer 4
   inner 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was a great help!